# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

In Simulator I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my iOS App when setting SKSpriteNode. It happens after I have set the SKSpriteNode in a loop 10 times with new values and added the Nodes to the view using addChild(). When I clear the view of all children (self.removeAllChildren) and want to set the SKSpriteNode again, the app crashes (only in the simulator).

Here is the code:

```
func drawCards(hand:[String], trick:[String]) {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    if (hand.count > 0) {
        for index in 0...(hand.count-1) {
            var xPosition = size.width
            let relativePosition = CGFloat(CGFloat(-hand.count) / 2.0 + CGFloat(index)) * 0.05
            xPosition *= ( 0.525 + relativePosition)
            var yPosition = size.height
            yPosition *= 3 * (cos(relativePosition * 0.5) - 1) + 0.05
            let card = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: hand[index]) // This is where the app crashes after the loop is called the second time
            card.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
            card.zRotation = -20 * CGFloat.pi / 180 * relativePosition
            card.scale(to: CGSize(width: 125, height: 182))
            card.zPosition = CGFloat(index)
            card.name = hand[index]
            addChild(card)
        }
    }
}
```

I have all the images in the asset catalog in all sizes (1x, 2x, 3x). This is the result I get when stepping into the indicated line of code:

```
@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10f3a9368)
```

The problem only arises in the simulator and only since I switched to xCode9/swift 4.0.

When I step through the code it looks like removeAllChildren does not clear the screen. Is that an asynchron method? Can I wait for it’s completion?

Comment: Is there logged error in console ?

Comment: In the console it only reads: (lldb)

Comment: That's the only thing? Could you log `hand`?

Comment: hand [String] 10 values
[0] String "queen_of_clubs"
etc... (alltogether 10 values)

Comment: Add a print after `self.removeAllChildren()`, and show all what's after it in Console.

Comment: Definitely sounds like there's a problem with the second image name in the `hand` array - putting this for loop aside, have you tried to just instantiate an SKSpriteNode with this image name?

Comment: @Larme: print(hand) you mean?